# How to Authenticate/Authorize the user with LDAP in Quarkus

Tags: ldap, quarkus

I have developed Quarkus Application.
I'm trying to authenticate the endpoint of Rest call via LDAP server.
Requirement is like, if user want to access the end point before that it authenticate the user that user belongs to Organization via Active Directory. if he belongs and got success then it should Authorize for the user.

Can any one help on this ? How to do authenticate in Quarkus Application in Java.

I already go through the https://quarkus.io/guides/security-ldap.
I also tried with configuration but getting the below error while binding or establishing the connection with LDAP server.

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this?
for error details pls see this image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSsps.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

have you read the security guides ?

see for example:
https://quarkus.io/guides/security-ldap

EDIT:

@Manish Chandel, you need to provide a username and password to connect to AD, and after that you can search it.

You need a config like this:

```
# put here the username path/DN to login to AD, something like: CN=..,OU=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com
quarkus.security.ldap.dir-context.principal=...
quarkus.security.ldap.dir-context.password=...

# you might need to add these 2 too, if you search from very high level path
# quarkus.security.ldap.dir-context.referral-mode=FOLLOW
# quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.search-recursive=true

# your search path, where the users can be found
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.search-base-dn=...

# the attribute name where the user account can be found, in AD it's usually sAMAccountName
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.rdn-identifier=sAMAccountName

# which attribute holds the role ? in AD it's usually memberOf
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.attribute-mappings."0".from=memberOf
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.attribute-mappings."0".to=groups

# the attributes to match the user account
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.attribute-mappings."0".filter=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))

# the path to find the roles
quarkus.security.ldap.identity-mapping.attribute-mappings."0".filter-base-dn...
```

Comment: Yeah, I already go through the security guides and it is not much clear or understandable. I also tried with configuration but it is not working for me.